# Internet disappears regularly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, linux-mint, internet

About a month ago I installed the newest version of Linux Mint (14).
I use Linux the whole day on my laptop but every 1-2 hours my internet connection (Wi-Fi) magically disappears for about 10 minutes.
I get this error when I try to open a website in Chrome:

> The server at google.com can't be found, because the DNS lookup
>   failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to
>   its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no
>   connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be
>   caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Google
>   Chrome from accessing the network.

There is also no "ping" when I open the terminal.

I also have Windows installed on the same machine, but I never experience issues like this while using Windows.
When the internet is gone on Linux, it's still available on my phone over the same Wi-Fi. So the internet connection itself works perfectly fine.

Does anybody have an idea?

**Update**:

It's me again. I used Windows for a while, but had to change to Linux again (Ubuntu  this time).
The last time, my connection disappeared, I tried the commands, suggested by jasonwryan and Bruce Ediger. These are my results:

```
$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ec:f4:bb:5e:3a:24  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7c00000-f7c20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2953 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2953 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:311476 (311.4 KB)  TX bytes:311476 (311.4 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:16:54:9d:62:5f  
          inet addr:192.168.178.20  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::fa16:54ff:fe9d:625f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:218583 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:120476 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:299458438 (299.4 MB)  TX bytes:12939161 (12

$ iw dev wlan0 link
Connected to 34:31:c4:67:9b:bc (on wlan0)
    SSID: FRITZ!Box 7312
    freq: 2412
    RX: 183533 bytes (212 packets)
    TX: 15958 bytes (227 packets)
    signal: -57 dBm
    tx bitrate: 115.6 MBit/s MCS 13 short GI

    bss flags:  short-preamble short-slot-time
    dtim period:    1
    beacon int: 100



$ dmesg
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.16.0-28-generic (buildd@komainu) (gcc version 4.9.1 (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6) ) #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 17:15:28 UTC 2014 (Ubuntu 3.16.0-28.37-generic 3.16.7-ckt1)
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-28-generic root=UUID=250ef3c4-35b0-4318-aac8-d6855bf852b1 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
[    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
[    0.000000] e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x00000000000913ff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000091400-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000cefe4fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cefe5000-0x00000000cefebfff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cefec000-0x00000000cf9e1fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cf9e2000-0x00000000cfeaafff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cfeab000-0x00000000d7db3fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000d7db4000-0x00000000d7ffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000d8000000-0x00000000d8758fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000d8759000-0x00000000d87fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000d8800000-0x00000000d8f99fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000d8f9a000-0x00000000d8ffffff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000d9000000-0x00000000da71bfff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000da71c000-0x00000000da7fffff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000da800000-0x00000000dbcf6fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000dbcf7000-0x00000000dbffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000dd000000-0x00000000df1fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f8000000-0x00000000fbffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed00000-0x00000000fed03fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed1c000-0x00000000fed1ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000021edfffff] usable
[    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
[    0.000000] SMBIOS 2.7 present.
[    0.000000] DMI: Dell Inc. Latitude E5540/0H56PP, BIOS A06 05/01/2014
[    0.000000] e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
[    0.000000] e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
[    0.000000] AGP: No AGP bridge found
[    0.000000] e820: last_pfn = 0x21ee00 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.000000] MTRR default type: uncachable
[    0.000000] MTRR fixed ranges enabled:
[    0.000000]   00000-9FFFF write-back
[    0.000000]   A0000-BFFFF uncachable
[    0.000000]   C0000-DBFFF write-protect
[    0.000000]   DC000-E7FFF uncachable
[    0.000000]   E8000-FFFFF write-protect
[    0.000000] MTRR variable ranges enabled:
[    0.000000]   0 base 0000000000 mask 7E00000000 write-back
//TOO LONG
```

The content of `/etc/resolv.conf` is:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search fritz.box
```

Neither `journalctl | tail` nor `/var/log/messages` were found.

Comment: Look in `/etc/resolv.conf` when your connection is up and then, when it goes down, check again...

Comment: After a while a added some updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this happens (during the 10 minutes of no Internet), run a few commands in a terminal window, as the root user or using `sudo`:

`ifconfig -a` - look for output concerning `wlan0`

`iw dev wlan0 link`

`dmesg`

`journalctl | tail` or if `journalctl` doesn't exist, look in `/var/log/messages`

Something in that output should give you more to go on.